# element complexType name attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, wsdl

Как добавить или изменить имя элемента ComplexType? Мне нужно чтобы было так:

```
<s:element name="recvMail">
   <s:complexType name="recvMail">
     <s:sequence>
       <s:element name="bMail"  type="tns:bMail"  minOccurs="0"/>
       <s:element name="bTrace" type="tns:bTrace" minOccurs="0"/>
       <s:element name="bBody"  type="tns:bBody"  minOccurs="0"/>
       <s:element name="bSign" type="s:string"   minOccurs="0"/>
     </s:sequence>
   </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

Вот мой код:

```
[WebMethod(BufferResponse = false, CacheDuration = 60, EnableSession = false)]
 [SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace = "http://temp.ws.uri/", ResponseNamespace = "http://temp.ws.uri/", Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal,
   ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
 [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("bAnswer")]
 public bAnswer recvMail(bMail bMail, bTrace bTrace, bBody bBody, string bSign) { ... }
```

Я использую ASP.NET .ASMX веб сервис
Почему та complexType без названия, никак не получается добавить ему названия 
В данный момент он выглядит так:

```
<s:element name="recvMail">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="bMail" type="tns:bMail"/>
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="bTrace" type="tns:bTrace"/>
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="bBody" type="tns:bBody"/>
                        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="bSign" type="s:string"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
```

Comment: Имя для complexType нужно лишь для того, чтобы использовать его для указания типа других элементов. В данном случае тип объявлен вложенным, поэтому имя как таковое не нужно. [Пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256067(v%3Dvs.100)#examples). | Его отсутствие приводит к каким-то проблемам?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но проблема в том что мой wsdl не парсится у стороннего шлюза, мне пишут что - Отсутствие имени типа в объектах recvMail, complexType тоже должен иметь имя.

Comment: Не понятно. Зачем ваш wsdl где-то парсится? На основе wsdl должен генерироваться код для работы с вашим сервисом. | Какому-то там шлюзу вы должны посылать сообщения, соответствующие некоему wsdl описанию. То есть именно готовые сообщения там парсятся, не?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Petrov Есть некий шлюз, который тянет наши методы, так вот наш wsdl не подходит им, их разработчик написал мне - Отсутствие имени типа в объектах recvMail, complexType тоже должен иметь имя. Как я понял complexType это тип элемента (класса), так вот мне нужно его указать, вот только не знаю как, я уже несколько дней мучаюсь с этим, походу навыков не хватает ((